# Getting proper float value in Jquery from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a ASP.Net Web API v2 to retrieve a list of products from the database. Using this web api i am obtaining a JSON that contains the data for my view and displaying it using jquery. However, the significant digits are being removed from the Price property upon getting the JSON.

For example -

```
<ArrayOfProductModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProductManagement.Models">
<ProductModel>
<Description>
Get ready to channel your inner dark knight with this epic Batman tee!
</Description>
<Id>1</Id>
<Imagepath>/Images/559276_1.jpg</Imagepath>
<Name>Batman T-Shirt (Men's)</Name>
<Price>996.0000</Price>
</ProductModel>
```

This is the XML from the API. And my Jquery Code:

```
var uri = '/api/Product';

$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON(uri).done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
        console.log(item.Price);
        var img='<img src='+item.Imagepath+' alt="productImage" height="150px" width="150px">'
        var $tr=$('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(item.Id),
            $('<td>').text(item.Name),
            $('<td>').text(item.Description),
            $('<td>').html(img),
            $('<td>').text(item.Price),
        );
        $('#productlist').append($tr);
    });
  });
});
```

Now console.log and the td tag with item.Price are both displaying 996 instead of 996.0000. Is there any way, i can prevent the significant digits from being removed?

Comment: Your 'JSON' looks suspiciously like XML to me...

Comment: Doesn't Web api return both XML and JSON? I mentioned that's it XML...i'm unable to force it to return JSON upon accessing /api/Products

Comment: You're right it does, it's just odd that you're making a request to get JSON yet in the question you formatted the response as XML. I was wondering how it was actually working without throwing any errors :)

Comment: To solve the problem try `item.Price.toFixed(2)`

Comment: Thanks, Rory, i guess i can use item.Price.toFixed(4) to fix this issue. Not sure why the significant digits are removed from the JSON by default though, any idea why?

Comment: It's the JS standard behaviour, as in most languages too. For example, C#: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3AxvK5

Comment: @SwayamDeepDash they are not significant digits as removing them doesn't change the numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

It's standard behaviour to remove trailing decimal zeroes from float values. If you need to retain them, you can use `toFixed()`, like this:

```
$('<td>').text(item.Price.toFixed(4))
```

One thing to note however is that `toFixed()` outputs a string, so you will need to convert it back to a float if you need to perform any mathematical operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('<td>').text(parseFloat(item.Price).toFixed(4)),
```